# Multiple upload sizes allowed in TinyMCE

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

The company I work for is running TinyMCE in a .NET environment for our merchants to upload files. Currently the maximum upload size variable that is loaded on the page is set to 25mb, but I've been made aware that depending on the merchant's package type, this could vary. I know where it is set in the config file, just wondering what the best way to go about a conditional way to set this value.